# Using R tidyverse I got This error on the filter Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found and I cant find a solution

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-analysis

Im learning R and using aprefunded database "ToothGrowth"Im learning to use Tidyverse and I have this block

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowt)
#will add name to the new data set and apply a filter filtered_tg <- filter (ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View(filtered_tg)
```

and getting this error on the filter Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found but is it like that on the data base , any idea? ) the videoinstructer it got fine [example of the instructur]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/W[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W%5Bcode) from the instructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfiU.png)RZD6.png)

Im trying to get the filter work and obtain this [result from the instructor after apply filter and view function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNX1b.png)

Comment: It might be that you haven't loaded the `dplyr` package, and so `R` is using the wrong version of the `filter` function. Try this: `dplyr::filter(ToothGrowth, dose==0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

The library that is accessed when I just specified filter() was the stats library[1], since you want to access the filter from dplyr, you can specify it as stated in the following code block. `filtered_tg <- dplyr::filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)`. You may face similar issues with arrange() too.

REFERENCES:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCcq1.png

Hope this solves your doubt,
Happy Coding!!!
Regards